# Jupyterhub helm install timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, jupyterhub

Environment setup:

3 Ubuntu VMs running Kubernetes Kubeadm install

- 1 control node
- 2 worker nodes

MetalLB deployment as load balancer for K8s

No out of the box storage classes or volumes.

I have been trying to simply install Jupyterhub using helm and am constantly running into various issues but the most recent one is a real head scratcher when I try to install it.

At this point I really need some help on a plain "local-storage" install, then use NFS for the user data in the future.  The Zero to Jupyterhub docs have been helpful but, not for this issue sorry to say.

```
dev@control1:~/jupyterhub$ helm upgrade --install jhub jupyterhub-1.2.0.tgz --values config.yml

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: pre-upgrade hooks failed: timed out waiting for the condition

dev@control1:~/jupyterhub$ helm list
NAME    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS  CHART                   APP VERSION
jhub    default         2               2022-01-10 18:16:58.570337598 +0000 UTC failed  jupyterhub-1.2.0        1.5.0
```

Here is my config.yml for the values:

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "xxxxxx"

singleuser:
  storage:
    type: dynamic
    dynamic:
      storageClass: local-storage
debug:
  enabled: true
```

here is my storage class for the local storage:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

I have tried various persistent volume files and none work, so I'll list them here anyway:

hub persistent volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: hub-db-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /tmp/jhub
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - worker1
```

Upon starting the install process, these are the only pods that are spun up:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hook-image-awaiter--1-brl2q   1/1     Running   0          47s
pod/hook-image-puller-9fghk       1/1     Running   0          47s
pod/hook-image-puller-scp88       1/1     Running   0          47s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   46d

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/hook-image-puller   2         2         2       2            2           <none>          48s

NAME                           COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/hook-image-awaiter   0/1           48s        48s
```

The helm debug logs show:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition
helm.go:88: [debug] failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition
INSTALLATION FAILED
main.newInstallCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:127
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:902
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:87
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:225
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
```

kubectl events show nothing out of the ordinary:

```
44m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate   daemonset/hook-image-puller       Created pod: hook-image-puller-scp88
44m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate   daemonset/hook-image-puller       Created pod: hook-image-puller-9fghk
35m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate   daemonset/hook-image-puller       Created pod: hook-image-puller-cx7sb
35m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate   daemonset/hook-image-puller       Created pod: hook-image-puller-mw6cd
9m10s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate   daemonset/hook-image-puller       Created pod: hook-image-puller-pgt4n
9m10s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate   daemonset/hook-image-puller       Created pod: hook-image-puller-p6h49
```

Comment: any errors in 'kubectl get events'?

Comment: @VasiliAngapov sorry, no errors, all looks normal:

```
9m10s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate   daemonset/hook-image-puller       Created pod: hook-image-puller-pgt4n
9m10s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate   daemonset/hook-image-puller       Created pod: hook-image-puller-p6h49

```

Comment: @VasiliAngapov  I updated the original post with the helm debug logs